# How to change class of a div when reach at 200px from top of the window using jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have 5 boxes on a webpage that you can see here:

http://demo.axistheme.com/methodology/Wakeup-Method.html.

The 1st box has the text 01 with a yellow background color and 2nd and the others have the text 02, 03 etc. with a gray background color.

When scrolling the window, how can I change the background color of each of the other boxes (one by one) at the point where they reach 200px beneath the top of the window?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check - whenever the window is scrolled - if any of the elements are less than `200px` from the top of the viewport.

To determine each element's vertical offset position relative to the viewport, you can subtract the window vertical scroll position (`$(window).scrollTop`) from each element's vertical offset position relative to the document (`.offset().top`).

*ie.* `var offsetTopPosition = $(ELEMENT).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();`

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        $('div').each(function(){

         var offsetTopPosition = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

         if (offsetTopPosition < 100) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
         }

         if (offsetTopPosition > 100) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
         }

        });

    });

});
```

```css
div {
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
line-height: 36px;
margin-bottom: 200px;
color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}

.active {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="active">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, is it possible to change 2nd box bgcolor when 1st box reach at top and change 3rd box bgcolor when 2nd box reach at top and same for other?

Comment: i did this by complex way. you can see here (http://demo.axistheme.com/methodology/Wakeup-Method.html). i want simple code.

Comment: @AxisTheme - I'm sure you understand that you have to write your own code. You use this site to ask for approaches. It's not site where people will do your homework for you. You have enough in the solution above to write your own solution. You can do it. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset() in combination with $(window).scrollTop() to determine the position of your elements.

```
    $('.box').each(function( index ) {
        var threshold = 200;
        var topOffset = $( this ).offset().top;
        if( topOffset - $(window).scrollTop() < threshold){
            $( this ).addClass('active');
       }else{
           $( this ).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```

See a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/yt584kLz/2/

Comment: Perfect, is it possible to change 2nd box bgcolor when 1st box reach at top and change 3rd box bgcolor when 2nd box reach at top and same for other?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the jsfiddle to change the next box color as well...
You can add all you want in the if/else block to target next or previous blocks. You might also be able to do it trough CSS alone. 

Just make sure that you have the order of the classes in your CSS the right way around, so that "active" class always has higher priority than the "nextActive"class. '

https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/yt584kLz/3/